# C++ vs. C# type safety

Tags: c#, c++, type-safety

I was reading through the questions with most votes from the [history](/questions/tagged/history) tag and came across  https://stackoverflow.com/q/4377512/627005, where the accepted answer states that C has "minimal type safety", C++ has "better type safety" and C# "has type safety". Why is C# more type safe than C++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ inherits lots of C features, so you can always do something unsafe if you want to. It's only that if you use C++ idiomatically, then you'll usually get type safety. There's just nothing that will categorically stop you if you choose to go off the safe grounds.

C# enforces a stronger type system and restricts the use of C-style constructions (most notably pointer arithmetic) to marked "unsafe" regions, so you have better (= automated) control over what is typesafe and what isn't.

---

*Digression:* It may be worthwhile to reflect a bit on what "safe" means. A language is called *safe* if we can verify that a particular piece of code is correct. In a statically typed language, this basically boils down to *type checking*: If we have an expression `a + b`, then we just check the types: `int` plus `int` equals `int`, fine; `struct` plus `union` makes no sense, compile error.

The odd man out in this setup is the dereference operator `*`: When we see `*p`, we can check that `p` is a pointer, but that is *not sufficient* to prove that the expression is correct! The correctness of the code does not only depend on the *type* of `p`, but also on its *value*. This is at the heart of the un-safety of C and C++.

Here are two examples to illustrate:

```
// Example #1
void print_two(const char * fmt)
{
  double d = 1.5;
  unsigned int n = 111;
  printf(fmt, d, n);
}

// Example #2
unsigned int get_int(const char * p)
{
  return *(unsigned int *)(p - 3);
}
```

In Example #1, the correctness of the code depends on the run-time supplied *value* of the string pointed to by `fmt`. In Example #2, we have the following:

```
unsigned int n = 5;
double d = 1.5;
const char * s = "Hello world";

get_int((char*)(&n) + 3);  // Fine
get_int((char*)(&d) + 3);  // Undefined Behaviour!
get_int(s + 5);            // Undefined Behaviour!
```

Again, just by looking at the code of `get_int()`, we *cannot* tell whether the program will be correct or not. It depends on how the function is used.

A safe language will not allow you to write such functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using `/unsafe`, the only somewhat type-unsafe operation in C# is typecasting - but it will throw an exception at the moment you perform the cast. In C++ `reinterpret_cast` et al could get you in a lot more troubles like access violations at actual pointer dereference.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is because they wrote it that way.

The simple how of it is .net doesn't allow untyped variables, and it will only allow operations that are defined for the type in question.

For more detail you need to read up in the CTS (Common Type System)

It was different languages, but still valid

The C compiler is an accomplice.

The .Net compiler is a policeman.....